# Using foreach to categorize data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I would like to know if it is possible to categorize data in groups when echoing it .

For example if I have a table of different phones and separate them by brand, i.e. Apple, Samsung etc, and I want the data to be displayed with a header of the brand of phone and under would have the phone type.

Apple
iphone 4
iphone 4s
iphone 5

Samsung
Galaxy Note 2
Galaxy S4

```
<div id="wrap">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo phones['brand']; ?></th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($phones as $phone): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $phone['name']); ?>
                        <br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo $phone['price']); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$<?php echo $phone['released']); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, sorry for the wait.

Comment: yes, this is possible.  please show us your best attempt at achieving your desired output.

Comment: what you're trying to do? you did anything?

Comment: Sorry, I edited in what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really basic example. Assuming you have your phones in an array like this:

```
$phones = [
    ['Apple',  'iphone 4'],
    ['Apple','iphone 4s'],
    ['Apple','iphone 5'],
    ['Samsung','Galaxy Note 2'],
    ['Samsung','Galaxy S4']
];
```

You just keep track of the brand as you output them, and whenever the brand is different from the previous brand, output a header for it.

```
$previous_brand = null;
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    list($brand, $model) = $phone;
    if ($brand != $previous_brand) {  // check if current brand is different than previous
        echo "<h3>$brand</h3>";
    }
    echo "$model<br>";
    $previous_brand = $brand;     // current brand becomes previous brand for next iteration
}
```

I kept the HTML minimal so it wouldn't be distracting from the working part. Obviously you can add whatever markup you need.

The important thing with this approach is that it *totally depends on your array being sorted by brand*, so if this is coming out of your database `ORDER BY brand`, or if it's some other source, [use one of the various PHP sort functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php) to get it in that order first.

Comment: My phones are in a mySQL database, would I have to do something different in the beginning?

Comment: Probably not much different. Just select all the phones you want to display, but be sure to add `ORDER BY brand`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about echoing it in table form?

Comment: That really depends on exactly how you want your table to be output. If you want a separate table for each brand it would be different than if you wanted them all in the same table separated by a differently formatted row or something like that. I intended the answer to be more of an example of how the PHP part works.

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
$phonesByBrand = [];

foreach ($phones as $phone)
{
  $phonesByBrand[$phone['brand']][] = $phone;
}
```

Now in your view, you can do

```
<?php foreach($phonesByBrand as $brand => $phones): ?>
  <div id="wrap">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><?php echo $brand; ?></th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($phones as $phone): ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $phone['name']); ?>
              <br>
              <ul>
                <li><?php echo $phone['price']); ?></li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              $<?php echo $phone['released']); ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```